# SPSS flag if there is text in variable

Tags: spss

I am new to SPSS (ver 25) and I am struggling with possibly easy thing - my variable is string, so there are, lets say drug names or client names or whatever the string is. I want to compute new variable that will flag them (give them value 1) if there is anything in the cell, and miss if cell is empty, so it would look like that

```
Var1 Var2
xxx   1
 -
yyy   1
zzz   1
```

and so on. It is easy when the var1 is numeric, but can't do when its string

I've tried something like this

```
IF NOT (var1="") var2 = 1 .
```

or

```
IF(NOT(var1="")) var2 = 1 .
```

but it creates empty numeric var2

Even on my guides it says

```
If(sysmis(var1)) var1new = 1.
```

however it seem to not work on SPSS ver.25

hope you can help me with this one thus save lot of work

Comment: Both ways you used should work (BTW  you can also use this: `if var1<>"" var2=1.` ). My guess is you just didn't run `pending transformations`. In the code just add another line with `execute.` and run it along with the other lines, then you will see the result of the calculations.

Comment: trey `IF NOT (RTRIM(var1)="") var2 = 1 .`. And, as @eli-k mentioned, do not forget to run `EXECUTE.` after your commands. But in any case, I am agree with eli-k, it is most likely the fact you did not execute the pending transformations

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the comments, there are many approaches to this task.  I'd advocate for issuing a COMPUTE command where you set the value of the new variable based on a logical condition:

COMPUTE flag = (CHAR.LENGTH(RTRIM(LTRIM(var1)))>0).

EXECUTE.

The above looks at the length of the trimmed string (spaces are trimmed off of the right and the left of the value).  If the cell was empty or contained blank spaces, the trimmed length would be zero (0), the condition would be 'false' and the new 'flag' variable would get a 0 value. If instead there was data present, the trimmed length will be > 0, the the condition is 'true' and the new 'flag' variable gets a 1 value.

Answer (score 0):

You were all right - I didn't set an execute. It is common mistake for me in SPSS

Moreover - I've managed it by doing AUTORECODE of this variable, then I got value of 1 for empty, then RECODEd (1=0)

Thank you very much for your help